# Example of a field that contains $\mathbb{C}$ as a proper subfield.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

We know that $\mathbb{C}$ (set of all complex numbers) is algebraically closed, so we have to think about non-algebraic extension.
Now, I found that $\mathbb{C}(X)$, the field of rational fractions coefficients from $\mathbb{C}$ is the field that contains $\mathbb{C}$ as a proper subfield.
$\mathbb{C}(X)$ is defined as :
$$\mathbb{C}(X)=\left\{ \dfrac{p(X)}{q(X)}  \ | \  (p(X), q(X)) \in \mathbb{C}[X]^2 \ \& \ q(X) \neq 0_{\mathbb{C}[X]} \right\}$$

*My doubt is* : Is $q(x)$ not identically zero or $q(x)$ has no zero in $\mathbb{C}$. Because we know every function (polynomial) has all it's zeros inside the field $\mathbb{C}$, by fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question - but does this 'answer' help? If one is confortable with $x+1$ as an element of $\mathbb C[x]$, one should be no less so with $1/(x+1)$ as an element of  $\mathbb C(x)$... Of course evaluating $1/(x+1)$ at $x=-1$ would be bad news.

Comment: The restriction is that $q(x)$ is not the polynomial that is identically zero. As you say, every polynomial (except for constants) is going to be equal to zero at at least one point of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: The name "rational functions" is unfortunate because $\Bbb C(x)$ is not a set of functions, but a set of **formal** quotients of **formal** polynomials, so there is no need to worry about the zeros of the denominators.

Comment: @EDX - When someone posts something they found confusing, your edit probably shouldn't change the part they found confusing. It makes it harder for future readers to understand the source of confusion, and answers no longer make sense.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thanks for you message. I understand. Actually the edits I've made don't interact with the doubt of Raja which still allows answer to be posted.

Comment: @EDX - I disagree. His question was which of "has a zero at any point" and "is the identically zero polynomial" was meant. By using $0_{\mathbb C [X]}$ you've removed the ambiguity. I'm not going to edit it back to Raja's original question, but I still think you should. Editing is a subtle thing, and I think the goal on math.se is to help the person better say what they meant, but not change what they said. Again, my claim is that you've changed what they said, but I leave it up to you.

Comment: BTW, I do think your edit clarified things, and using the symbol $0_{\mathbb C[X]}$ to respond was a good idea, but it's an answer to their question, so it belongs as an answer (or maybe a comment), not as an edit to their question.

Comment: I understand your point of view. Thanks for sharing it.